# MongoDB.Driver with C#.NET Core Data Not Saved

Tags: c#, mongodb, connectivity

I am working to connect C# Console Application with MongoDb. MongoDb Server is up and running as I can work on it with Mongobooster IDE and command prompt. I have installed latest official MongoDB.Driver for connectivity v2.4.1 so basically I cann't use db.document.Save method as solution. In this application I used db.document.insert method below is the code has compiled successfully and executed but my data has not been stored on server. I am working with .NET Core so I can't go to older version of Drivers as they are not supported .NET Core.

Student Model

```
public class Students
{
  public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Connection object and Student object

```
protected static IMongoClient _client;
protected static IMongoDatabase _database;

public static Students GetStudent()
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter student first name");
    string FNm = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter student last name");
    string LNm = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter student age");
    string StudentAge = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter city name");
    string StudentCity = Console.ReadLine();

    Students student = new Students()
    {
      FirstName = FNm,
      LastName = LNm,
      Age = StudentAge,
      City = StudentCity,
    };

    return student;
}
```

Main Method

```
_client = new MongoClient();
_database = _client.GetDatabase("School");
var _collection = _database.GetCollection<Students>("StudentDetails");

Console.WriteLine("Press select your option from the following\n1 - Insert\n2 - Update One Document\n3 - Delete\n4 - Read All");

string userSelection = Console.ReadLine();


switch (userSelection)
 { 
    case "1":
      _collection.InsertOne(GetStudent());
    break;

    case "2":

    break;
.....
```

Comment: Your code is ok, InsertOne should add a document to collection. Are you sure, that it was really exectued? Perhaps was userselection "2"? How do you check, that your data was saved? Do you use some mongodb client? Query in console?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any classmaps inplace? I guess it maps your

```
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

to the documents "_id" field.
You dont specify a value for this field, try:

```
Students student = new Students()
{
  Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(),
  FirstName = FNm,
  LastName = LNm,
  Age = StudentAge,
  City = StudentCity,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

On console window it stopped executing the server code, once I clicked `ctrl + z` it executed!

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14922125)

Comment: @hardillb, I am not very sure what exactly was the problem and I don't see any specific reason that server console stopped due to loosing focus in window. So I am marking my answer as accepted answer to complete the thread.